# Filter key-values from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries and I need to filter that list where a certain key has a certain value. For example, only `dict`s where `'name'` is `'Joel'` or `'Ellie'`.

```
dict1 = {'name': 'Joel', 'age': 48, 'brother': 'Tommy'}
dict2 = {'name': 'Tommy', 'age': 43, 'brother': 'Joel'}
dict3 = {'name': 'Ellie', 'age': 14, 'brother': None}

list_of_dicts = [dict1, dict2, dict3]

# <output>
[{'name': 'Joel', 'age': 48, 'brother': 'Tommy'},
{'name': 'Tommy', 'age': 43, 'brother': 'Joel'},
{'name': 'Ellie', 'age': 14, 'brother': None}]
```

Desired output:

```
[{'name': 'Joel', 'age': 48, 'brother': 'Tommy'},
{'name': 'Ellie', 'age': 14, 'brother': None}]
```

Comment: maybe a list comprehension should do: `[d for d in list_of_dicts if d.get('name') in ('Joel', 'Ellie')]`

Comment: How could you not find something about this on SO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the below code, this might help you:

```
[value for value in list_of_dicts if value.get('name') in ['Joel', 'Ellie']]
```

So your code will be:

```
dict1 = {'name': 'Joel', 'age': 48, 'brother': 'Tommy'}
dict2 = {'name': 'Tommy', 'age': 43, 'brother': 'Joel'}
dict3 = {'name': 'Ellie', 'age': 14, 'brother': None}

list_of_dicts = [dict1, dict2, dict3]
final_list = [value for value in list_of_dicts if value.get('name') in ['Joel', 'Ellie']]
print(final_list)
```